# How to break out a loop using a counter

Tags: javascript

Looking for a logic possibly using a for loop to loop through orders for an ordering system using Shopify. Order IDs come in sequentially, as they come in we want to assign a pickup location based on the order number.

For example, first 100 orders will have the pickup location set to Location A and next 100 to Location B and so on. But once we reach the 500 order, we want to start again from Location A and then loop through the locations. There will be no end to this loop until the orders stop.

All orders get prepared at a central location and gets dispatched to the corresponding location.  OrderID is created once the order is placed on the website so we want the pickup location shown at the final Order Status page.

Please let me know if I can provide clarification.

I can achieve this logic by If statements by static assignment of Order IDs and of course this is not scalable as we don't know how many orders we will get.

```
<script>
  var orderId = {{ order_number }};
if (orderId > 100) {
  Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox(
    '<h3> Pickup Location A</h3>'
)}
 else {
  Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox(
    '<h2>Pickup Location</h2>'    
  )}
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... do you want to alternate between location A and location B every 100 orders? Also, do you have an array with all the orders or do they come in 1 at a time?

Comment: Orders come one at a time. We want to loop through 4 to 5 locations after every 100 orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? The first 100 orders go to `A`, second 100 to `B`, ..., fifth 100 to `E` then it starts cycling (sixth 100 go to `A`, seventh 100 go to `B`, ...).

```js
const orderId = prompt('Enter an order number'); //TODO: set to actual order number
const pickupLocations = [
 ['<h3>Pickup Location A</h3>', '<img src="https://dummyimage.com/30&text=A"></img>'],
 ['<h3>Pickup Location B</h3>', '<img src="https://dummyimage.com/30&text=B"></img>'],
 ['<h3>Pickup Location C</h3>', '<img src="https://dummyimage.com/30&text=C"></img>'],
 ['<h3>Pickup Location D</h3>', '<img src="https://dummyimage.com/30&text=D"></img>'],
 ['<h3>Pickup Location E</h3>', '<img src="https://dummyimage.com/30&text=E"></img>']
];
const pickupIndex = Math.floor(orderId/100) % pickupLocations.length;

//TODO: comment out console.log() in favor of next line
console.log(...pickupLocations[pickupIndex]);    
//Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox(...pickupLocations[pickupIndex]);
```

Comment: This seems to be working but how does the script keep track of the number of orders when they arrive one at a time?

Comment: It doesn't. It assumes the `orderId` is increased by 1 for each order. If that's not true, we'll have to figure out a way to store `orderCount` in some sort of persistent way. For example if not all orders should count toward the threshold that causes moving to the next pickup location... then we have more work to do.

Comment: Orders do increment sequentially and all orders count toward the threshold. Can you please explain how the array index is obtained by doing this - % pickupLocations.length.

Comment: Sure. `Math.floor` rounds down `orderId/100` so 0-99 becomes 0, 100-199 becomes `1` etc. Then we do ` % pickupLocations.length` which gives us the remainder after dividing `Math.floor(orderId/100)` by `pickupLocations.length`. You can think of it as subtracting `pickupLocations.length` until the result is `< pickupLocations.length` and then giving us that number.

Comment: can i also ask how i can include a img tag for each location in the array so it returns a small image along with the location name. Thank you again.

Comment: Easy, you just add an image tag. '<h3>Pickup Location A <img src="https://dummyimage.com/30"></img></h3>'.

Comment: yep i thought of that but i want to image to appear in the next line under the location next. So it needs to be a separate element in the content box, see below.  

Shopify.Checkout.OrderStatus.addContentBox(
    '<h3> Pickup Location: Location A</h3>', 
'<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0036/6808/2737/files/Logo_216x400_c90ef569-73cb-447d-86de-8034f6c49ee1_108x200.jpg">' 
)}

Comment: Could you just do `<h3>...</h3><br/><img></img>`? or does it need to be a second parameter passed to `addContentBox`?

Answer (score -1):

I think this does what I think you're asking.

```
pickupLocations = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
pickupGroup = 0;
orderCounter = 1;

for (orderID=1, orderID < orderIDs.length; orderID++) {
   pickup = pickupLocations[pickupGroup];
   if (orderCounter==100) {
      pickupGroup++;
      orderCounter=0;
   }
}
```

If you really want to break out, you can use the "break;" command.  Or, to  have the loop run only while a condition is met, "while (condition) {...}".

Comment: Orders come one at a time and it is not an array.

Comment: Well then, you need to save the number of the order you're on somewhere.  For example, use AJAX to run a script to get the number of orders that have been processed so far from a file on the server, then add 1 to it, then save that file back to the disk. If your page is generated by a server-side script, have that script load and update the counter file, then draw a hidden field with the value of the order number for Javascript to grab.